# Step size in scipy optimize minimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I am running simulations by varying 3 parameters. For each simulation I calculate an index that tells me if the simulation is improving (lower index).
To do this, I'm using `scipy.optimize.minimize` but I'm not sure which method is best (I'm trying to learn more).

```py
def launcher(x0):
    #varying parameters#
    varying_p(x0[0], x0[1], x0[2])
    run_sim(simulation)
    results = import_results(simulation)
    indexes = index_calc(Data_from,Data_to,simulation,results)
    value = indexes['CHI_tot'].iloc[-1]
    return value
```

Each parameter varies in a range that I indicate with "bounds".

When I launch the simulation each parameter is varied with very small steps. There would be a way to define not only the range of variation but also the steps for each parameter (For example with a step of `50`)

This could help to obtain more quickly a result of the optimization?

```py
v_cp = 999.209
v_rho = 1249.94
v_lambda = 0.2815

initialcond = np.array([v_cp, v_rho, v_lambda])
# Bounds: valid only for method L-BFGS-B, TNC, SLSQP, Powell, and trust-constr
bounds = [(400,1600), (400,1600), (0.1, 1.2)]

res = minimize(launcher, initialcond , bounds=bounds, method='L-BFGS-B', options = {'maxiter':10})

print(res.x)
```

Comment: Welcome! At least for me, it would be helpful if you work out a bit more what you want to achieve. First of all, I am wondering whether your `launcher` is actually a smooth function (which is a prerequisite for the gradient-based `L-BFGS-B`). Moreover, the step in parameter space is given by the very mature underlying math; I doubt you can speed this up a lot with manual step-size control. How much do you know about `L-BFGS-B` and what exactly do you want to control?

Comment: Thank you for the timely response. Unfortunately, I know very little about L-BFGS-B and am looking to learn more about it. 
The function invokes a simulation software which in turn launches a simulation. The data obtained I compare with experimental data. Always in python I calculate a statistical index that tells me if I'm approaching the real measured data. 
So I don't know how to intend in this case a smooth function. 
I have tried to print all the attempts that tries the optimizer (839.844919951963) . Maybe I should change the method type?

Comment: Note that this algorithm approximates gradients by finite differences. That is probably the small step sizes you see, It is better to use a Derivative Free (DFO) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All SciPy gradient-based optimizers (L-BFGS-B, SLSQP, etc...) expect - obviously - a gradient of the objective function. If you don’t provide it, they will try to calculate one numerically for you, using some ridiculously small step size (like 10^-6). That’s probably what you’re seeing. A couple of “workarounds”:

1. I seem to remember that some optimizers allow you to set a step size for gradient calculations (“eps” parameter)
2. (Better) Normalize your parameters between 0 and 1 when calling the optimizer and de-normalize them before calling the external simulator.